# Remove border around image

Tags: html, css

guys. I style little form with submit button. 
It looks like:
[image]

As you can see there is some white background around submit image and I don't have idea why! Image is cut fine and I always cut image with transparent background.

my HTML:

```
<form action="#">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>
<input type="submit" class="join-us" value="PŘIDEJ SE K NÁM">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.join-us{
    background-image: url("images/join_us.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:181px;
    height: 114px;
    line-height: 114px;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    white-space: nowarp;
}
```

Live website can be find on http://funedit.com/andurit/new

Can you help me to remove that white backgroun from there?

Comment: Kindly attach the image if border:none; doesn't work

Comment: border as none works just checked on your live site.

Comment: add `border:none;` to `.join-us`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a white background, it's the `input` element's border. Just remove it using CSS by adding the following rule to the `.join-us` class:

```
border: none;
```

It seems that you also need to adjust the height of the button to `106px`, so your final class definition will look like this:

```
.join-us{
    background-image: url("images/join_us.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:181px;
    height: 106px;
    line-height: 106px;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: hey it remove white space but not from bottom

Comment: i had to set height as well, anyway u have thumb up from me, thanks for help

Comment: Yes, I explained about setting the height, maybe you missed it? Anyway, you might want to accept the answer if it helped?

Answer (score 2):

Setting

```
border: none;
```

is an important part to remove the standard <button>-style. However, in your case it is not quite enough: You also have to set

```
height: 106px;
```

Since your image is only that high.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Background of input.

You can easily remove this white border, by setting the CSS property `border:none;`,

[image]
And the bottom white background is due to your `Image`. It's because your image have some transparent area at the bottom.
If you want to remove it, you can try to set `height: 106px;` into CSS class `.join-us`.
After doing this your Input look like this : -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As buttons have there default border style, you need to overwrite that:

```
border:none;
```

so ur css should be:

```
.join-us{
    background-image: url("images/join_us.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width:181px;
    height: 114px;
    line-height: 114px;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor:pointer;
    white-space: nowarp;
    .join-us{
        background-image: url("images/join_us.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width:181px;
        height: 114px;
        line-height: 114px;
        color: #f7f7f7;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        cursor:pointer;
        white-space: nowarp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following CSS to your `.join-us` class

```
border:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your background image height and input height are not equals. So as you see under image you have a void space that shows background-color.

So yaou have to set background-color equals transparent or change input height.

Use this:

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: url("images/join_us.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 0 none;
color: #F7F7F7;
cursor: pointer;
height: 114px;
line-height: 114px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
vertical-align: top;
width: 181px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.join-us {
    height:106px;
    border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add both of these styles to your `.join-us` class.

```
border: none;
background-size: 100% 108%;
```

The `border` style will remove the small while line around your image. The `background-size` style will stretch out the image to fit perfectly into your class background with no white space.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `border: 2px outset buttonface;` from your stylesheet.